# When using WHERE NOT IN, It returns one of WHERE IN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is the sql code:

```
SELECT s_id FROM questions WHERE s_id NOT IN (:ids)
```

IDs are 1,2 and there is only 2 line in the table. But that selects the line 2, anyway. Where is the problem that I make??

Comment: Add your sample dataset in http://sqlfiddle.com/ and add in your question

Comment: You've not shown any PHP, but I'll hazard a guess that you're using PDO, which doesn't have built-in support for binding an array of params for IN.

Comment: @Alexander - of course it has. The SQL is good, the problem is, obviously, how he make the parameterized query in PHP. We lack to see the PHP code!

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition?rq=1 for how you could handle this in PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s_id FROM questions WHERE s_id NOT IN (:ids)
```

This has a placeholder for exactly *one* value, `:ids`. If you're binding the value like:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':ids', '1,2');
```

Well, guess what, you've just bound *one* value "1,2". This is the same as:

```
SELECT s_id FROM questions WHERE s_id NOT IN ('1,2')
```

Which is *not* the same as

```
SELECT s_id FROM questions WHERE s_id NOT IN (1, 2)
```

If you want to bind more than one value, you need more than once placeholder. Placeholders stand in for values, they're not like copy and pasted SQL snippets.